# How can i setup a network Lexmark MS812dn?

Tags: networking, printing, software-installation, lexmark

I have installed the drivers but i don't know how to setup the printer itself to actually print something. Do i have to plug an ethernet cable to the laptop or to a network connection? Which address should i put in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Connectivity Guide (Lexmark MS810,MS811,MS812)

http://www.lexmark.com/publications/pdfs/2007/ms81x/hmp_2.4/en/connectivity-guide.pdf

---

### Drivers (Lexmark MS812dn, MS812dtn)

[Download here](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=EN&page=product&userlocale=EN_US&productCode=LEXMARK_MS812&focusedTab=DOWNLOADS#1)

---

### Other Manuals you might find useful (Lexmark MS812dn)

[Here](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=EN&page=product&userlocale=EN_US&productCode=LEXMARK_MS812&focusedTab=PUBLICATIONS#1)

---

### Obtain a copy of the software installer package.

You can obtain it from either the Software and Documentation CD that came with your printer or from [www.lexmark.com](http://www.lexmark.com). (navigate to Support > Drivers & Downloads > Select your printer > Select your Operating System > download your software installer package)

From the research I have gathered, the Lexmark MS812dn drivers are only supported on Ubuntu 12.04, 11.10, 11.04, 10.10 and 10.04.

Comment: Basically it says what to do for windows/mac but not for Ubuntu. Apart from the technical part which is ok the soft part does not help me :(

Comment: @CodreanuLaurentiu, It's all there. I have updated my answer in hope to help you out further.